# Returning Null or Nothing from VBScript function?

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to write the VBScript equivalent of a function similar to what's below:

```
object getObject(str)
{
    if ( ... )
    {
        return object_goes_here;
    }

    return null;
}
```

My guess would be below, except that I'm not understanding the difference between Nothing and Null.  As a caller, I'd rather test if the return value is set by using `IsNull()` versus `X Is Nothing`.

```
Function getObject(str)
    If ... Then
        Set getObject = object_goes_here
        Exit Function
    End If

    Set getObject = Nothing  // <-- or should this be Null?
End Function
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The correct way to not return an object is to return `Nothing` and test for `Is Nothing`.

VB's `Null` is a special value of type Variant/Null. There are other special values, such as Variant/Empty or Variant/Error. They all have their use, but it's not the one.

Comment: How is InStr getting away with it?  It looks like it returns the .NET equivalent of a Nullable<int>.  http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_instr.asp

Comment: @jglouie `InStr` accepts a `VARIANT` as its parameter, not an object. It then examines the `VARIANT` and tries to give you what you expected. Returning a `Null` if a string operand is `Null` is a very standard common concept coming from databases. As for strings in VB6 (and VBScript), they are not objects anyway, they cannot be `Nothing`. Well, they sort of can, but that's called `vbNullString` and is not detected with `Is Nothing`.

Answer (score 4):

Use the second Function skeleton. Avoid Null when dealing with objects, because of the Set Assignment abomination.

```
Dim oX : Set oX = getObject(...)
If oX Is Nothing Then
   ...
Else
  nice object to work with here
End If
```

vs

```
Dim vX : vX = getObject(...) ' <-- no Set, no object
If IsNull(vX) Then
   ...
Else
   no object to work with here
End If
```

Answer (score 3):

In your sample code, the object gets always `Nothing` because that is the last action. This is how it should be:

```
Function getObject(str)
     If ... Then
         Set getObject = object_goes_here
         Exit Function
     End If
     Set getObject = Nothing
End Function
```

or:

```
Function getObject(str)
     Set getObject = Nothing  
     If ... Then
         Set getObject = object_goes_here
     End If
End Function
```

The answer of GSerg is correct: you should use Nothing. Additionally, to see if an object has a null reference, use:

```
If Not object Is Nothing Then
    '  do something
End If
```

Comment: Oops, I left out the Exit Function line, thanks.  That wasn't my question but it'll clarify anyone else searching for this question.